# Java source code generation frameworks

Tags: java, code-generation

I have a set of Java 5 source files with old-style Doclet tags, comments and annotations. And based on that I would like to write a generator for another set of Java classes.

What is the best way to do that? And are there any good standalone libraries for code analysis/generation in Java? Any shared exprience in this field is appreciated.

So, far I have found these:

- [JaxME's Java Source Reflection](http://ws.apache.org/jaxme/js/jparser.html) - seems good, but it does not seem to support annotations. Also it had no release since 2006.
- [Annogen](http://annogen.codehaus.org/) - uses JDK's Doclet generator, which has some bugs under 1.5 JDK. Also it had no releases for a long time.
- [Javaparser](http://code.google.com/p/javaparser/) - seems good as well and pretty recent, but only supports Visitor pattern for a single class i.e. no query mechanism like in the 2 above packages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both the NetBeans IDE and Eclipse JDT projects have considerable Java code analysis/generation logic. I don't know what their dependencies are (i.e., can you use them as standalone libs), but other than that, I would take a good look at those two: it's unlikely there's a java code analysis library under more intensive development and more up to date.

Update:

[PMD](http://pmd.sourceforge.net/) might be of interest as well:

> PMD scans Java source code and looks for potential problems like:
>
> ```
> * Possible bugs - empty try/catch/finally/switch statements
> * Dead code - unused local variables, parameters and private methods
> * Suboptimal code - wasteful String/StringBuffer usage
> * Overcomplicated expressions - unnecessary if statements, for loops that could be while loops
> * Duplicate code - copied/pasted code means copied/pasted bugs
> ```

Additionally, this [blog](http://weblogs.java.net/blog/fabianocruz/archive/2006/10/java_static_ana.html) entry discusses various static code analysis tools.

Comment: Eclipse has JET (Java Emmiter Templates), but it does not work outside Eclipse (http://wiki.eclipse.org/JET_FAQ_How_do_I_run_a_JET_transformation_from_Java%3F).

Comment: I've updated my answer with a couple of new items.

Comment: I have tried to play a bit with PMD, but it's API is a bit too complex.   I will continue on experimenting and post you my results.

Comment: I ended up using PMD together with its AST and XPath.

Comment: Posted an example as a separate answer.

Answer (score 4):

If you only need to generate syntactically correct Java code, check the [Codemodel](https://codemodel.java.net/).

Comment: Codemodel is just a code generator, and it does not have a tool for parsing java code. Though +1 for the link :).

Comment: Yes, it is _only_ a code generator, I'd like emphasize that once again. Very nice API to my taste.

Comment: The URL seems to have changed to http://codemodel.java.net/

Comment: It's a great framework - however, the project seems inactive since almost 2 years.

Comment: @MRalwasser Codemodel is used in XJC (schema compiler from JAXB RI) so be sure that Oracle will keep it alive. :)

Comment: @lexicore that's true but it seems that this at least happens not publicly on java.net. The mailing lists seem dead and there are no responses at the issue tracker at all.

Answer (score 3):

I ended up using PMD. Code example can be seen below:

```
    final Java15Parser parser = new Java15Parser();
    final FileInputStream stream = new FileInputStream("VehicleServiceType.java");

    final Object c = parser.parse(new InputStreamReader(stream));

    final XPath xpath = new BaseXPath("//TypeDeclaration/Annotation/NormalAnnotation[Name/@Image = 'WebService']",
        new DocumentNavigator());

    for (final Iterator iter = xpath.selectNodes(c).iterator(); iter.hasNext();) {
      final Object obj = iter.next();
      // Do code generation based on annotations...
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, nice to know you can traverse a class definition using XPath!

Answer (score 0):

it's not exactly a code generator, but if you need some bean-related functionality, apache beanutils is a time-saver

http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-beanutils/javadocs/v1.9.1/apidocs/org/apache/commons/beanutils/package-summary.html#dynamic